# ReactJS Invalid Checksum

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting the following error when attempting server side rendering using ReactJS & node.

```
React attempted to use reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid.
```

I've seen an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978946/facebook-react-js-how-do-you-render-statefull-components-on-the-server) that passing the same props on the server and client resolves this issue. In my example, I don't have any props, so I'm not sure that the answer applies to my problem.

You can view my full example on my [github](https://github.com/maestroh/react-server-rendering) account.

I'm including the important code below. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

**JSX**

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var index = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <html>
          <head>
            <script src="bundle.js"></script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div>
              hello
           </div>
          </body>
         </html>
     );
   }
});

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  React.renderComponent(<index/>, document.documentElement);
} else {
  module.exports = index;
}
```

**Server**

```
require('node-jsx').install();
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express(),
    React = require('react'),
    index = require('./index.jsx');

var render = function(req, res){
  var component = new index();
  var str = React.renderComponentToString(component);
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.send(str);
  res.end();
}

app.get('/',render);
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change

```
React.renderComponent(<index/>, document.documentElement);
```

to

```
React.renderComponent(<index/>, document);
```

and the notice goes away.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sometimes, it's something so simple. Thank you. How did you know the answer so quickly?

Comment: I had a hunch so I played around with it. :) In hindsight, `document.documentElement` *is* the HTML element, and `document` *contains* it, and React renders into elements—so if you want to render the `html` tag, you have to render into its container.

Comment: Great response. Thank you again!

Comment: A similar answer applies if you're rendering into a div instead of rendering into `<html>` -- you need to create a wrapper div and render into that.